# Terraform - merging top-level resource arguments

Tags: terraform

Is it possible to somehow define a map-variable or something like that and then expand it into top-level resource arguments? Similar to how you can do `<<:` in yaml.

I've looked into merging maps and override files but looks like they are not suited for this.

Example, I have something like this

```
resource "resource_type" "res1" {
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  special = "res1"
}

resource "resource_type" "res2" {
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  special = "res2"
}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
locals {
  common_args = {
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
  }
}
  
resource "resource_type" "res1" {
  <put content of locals.common_args here>
  special = "res1"
}

resource "resource_type" "res2" {
  <put content of locals.common_args here>
  special = "res2"
}
```

Comment: You can iterate over the resources with all of your identical argument values hardcoded, and the dynamic value different for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you can merge the resource blocks by using `count=` or `for_each`, that would probably be best. You can still calculate a separate "special" etc. for each iteration.

But if they have to be separate, then something like this pattern of resource attributes in each block should work: `a = local.common_args["a"]`